# ArgumentError with rails 3.2.0.rc1 stylesheet_link_tag in skeleton application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a new rails 3.2.0.rc1 app and generated a welcome controller with an index action.  I fixed the routes so that root points to this action and I removed the index.html placeholder file.  When I try and load the root page I am getting an error "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" related to welcome.css.scss and the stylesheet_link_tag line in application.html.erb.  If I rename the welcome.css.scss file to welcome.css, the page loads fine.

Did I miss a special config step for the release candidate?  I am using ruby 1.9.2.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the stacktrace from this error please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was `rc1` bug.

I've just switched on `rails 3.2.0.rc2`, and this problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same with 3.2rc1 on 1.9.3-p0

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-08 21:18:59 -0800
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 81ms

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
  (in /Users/dan/Sites/appname/app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.scss)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Appname</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3426015066428469059_70355741377500'


  Rendered /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (9.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/dan/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (15.2ms)
```

My home.css.scss is as follows

```
// Place all the styles related to the home controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
```

Comment: I have exactly same problem on rails 3.2.0.rc1